# How to edit a row in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have records that are displayed on a page and I have a small "edit" icon on the very right of each row.

So when I click the icon I want the user to edit "selected" row.

Now, I am generating the records and images behind code! so i am not using a control it generated a html code then i do something like this

```
output.InnerHTML = generatedCode;
```

Question, how can i create a function to determine which icon has been clicked and also that id of that icon?

Comment: Rows of _what_? How are you generating these rows?

Comment: I suggest using a gridview. It has these features built-in.

Comment: I think he is using a gridview or some row like control. Can we get the code on how you generate the rows!

Comment: No i am not using a grid control. I pull data from the database then i put them in a dataset. then i loop thru them and i generate a HTML table then i output in! so i don't use gridview!

Comment: Is there a reason to not use a gridview?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this with tables you must generate some unique id for each row edit link so that you can identify which row you have to edit. Apart from this there are pretty much easy way to display records in asp.net i.e `GridView`

Comment: I am not using a gridview however, i can give each image input a uniqe id!

Comment: I have tried doing something like this <a href="?id=53456434">Edit</a> but every time the use clicks on edit like IsPostBack return true and that change the whole page!!

Comment: I am considering you are generating two kind of rows one for displaying and other for editing, on click use `Request.QueryString["id"]` and filling the edit row controls with the data, on update you can detect id by placing that in a hidden field in edit row.

Comment: Okay after many people suggesting to use gridview. I have changed this code to use gridview! I did the select part and put everything in a gridview and also I have enabled the delete and edit futures! So now I see (edit/remove) next to each row! I must say that I identify the select sqlsoutce and select command in behind code. How can I identify the update and delete code in behind code? What is the correct way of handelling on updating and on remove?   Thanka

Comment: there are `RowUpdating`, `RowDeleting`, `RowUpdating`, `RowCancelling` Events of gridview for CRUD operations. `EditIndex` is an important property to remember which is default -1 and has to be changed to `e.NewEditIndex` for editing. `e.RowIndex` gives you the current operated row. for further details refer to this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23471/Editable-GridView-in-ASP-NET-2-0